# Solaris 10 - Why shell limits needs to be increased to run oracle database?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

Shell limits affect shell and scripts running shell like bash.
Oracle's requirements (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/install.112/e48357/pre_install.htm#SSDBI1182 - section 2.10) is to modify these values to a given minimum and to set them to unlimited in production environment.

If the oracle database run a set of binaries, how would changing ulimits affect the database?

Comment: Shell limits affect the shell and all processes it starts.

Comment: You change the memory and file limits on database servers so that the database can access more resources than users generally need on regular Unix/Linux servers. As long as I have worked with Oracle, about 17 years, you always need to change the memory and file limits on Unix/Linux servers.

Comment: I am aware of that too and have been doing that religiously in the past.
I've joined a new company and discovering this new system. I noticed that problem but our sys admin is reluctant to change it saying that it affects only shell and oracle rdbms are binaries.

I try to find clear explanations on how this limit is used by oracle. I know (or rather I assume) it is but I don't know how exactly.

Comment: This is from oracle's documentation:"
Now this can be changed by running the ulimit -d unlimited but after a reboot this value will
default back to 2097148. To change this permanently just add this into the system's /etc/.login and the /etc/profile files and thus the ulimit will be changed."

This would be a system wide change too. so I want to set it in .bash_profile for oracle user. But how would the database use and benefit from it? This is the question I'm asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle might be binary, but it will still initiate system commands which in term could involve shells. On UNIX systems, the ulimit command controls the limits on system resource, such as process data size, process virtual memory, and process file size. It is also mostly the users processes affect parent processes. So the parent processes manage the users. Normally ulimit is inherited from the main user, so allowing you to set a value for Oracle might be in the interest of your system administrator. In Solaris it is ulimited. ulimit -Ha and ulimit -Sa will show the hard and soft limits. Good rule of thumb is to ensure the soft limits do not exceed the hard. But unlimited for a dedicated Oracle server would be better.